# Rule of thumb for designing protocol messages

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a very simple music player, and I'd like to make it into a music server.
I plan in using gRPC to communicate between the clients and the server. 
However, I'm not sure how I should design the protocol messages to handle the playback.

I envision two types of design :

- A message for each type of query. This method defines clearly all possible actions, but seems to create a lot of redundant code.

  ```
  message Play{
      bool flag = 1; // False means Pause
  }
  message Stop{
     bool flag = 1;
  }
  ```
- A unique message, with a key containing the action. This approach seems more flexible, but also more prone to errors. I could use an enum object to limits the possible actions though.

  ```
  message Playback{
      enum Action {
          PLAY = 0;
          STOP = 1;
      }
      Action action = 1;
  }
  ```

Basically, I guess that what's I'm asking here is whether I should define an action by the type of the message or by its content.

Is there a rule of thumb or a design pattern to apply here ?

Comment: is a command ever more complex than an `enum` value? i.e. does `Playback` actually encompass everything? Side note: you might also want to look at `oneof`; it may be useful here

Comment: Well, based on this [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_controls), I guess that `Playback` does not need to encompass more than one `enum` value. Thanks for the tip about `oneof`, seems useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `oneof` construct here:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Play {
}

message Stop {
}

message Command {
    oneof command {
         Play play = 1;
         Stop stop = 2;
         ...
    }
}
```

Empty messages are fine when there are no parameters that you need to pass, and this also leaves open an easy way to extend the messages in the future, for example changing `Play` to:

```
message Play {
    string filename = 1;
}
```

would allow including an optional filename with the request, while retaining compatibility with the old version.